# Show sent request in groovy script in SoapIU

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I try to create integration tests in SoapUI:

1. There are property `myId=1234` in property file.
2. I send soap request (named myRequest) contains `<messageId>${myId}</messageId>`
3. This request is valid, because ${myId} is replaced by 1234. I receive response.
4. In my groovy script I want show sent request, value of `<messageId>`:

```groovy
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def request = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("myRequest#Request");

log.info(request["//messageId"]);
```

output: `${myId}`

Expected output: `1234`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you show the raw request? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Raw request is in point one: `<messageId>${messageId}</messageId>`

Comment: That was not helpful. Do you just wanted to show entire request that was sent along with variables being replaced? or just only that particular value? Any way, provide more details with context.

Comment: Yes, I want to show entire request that was sent along with variables being replaced.

Comment: Radosolav, please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible achieve this without using an additional `Groovy Script` test step by using `Script Assertion` for the same request step.

Use below `Script Assertion` to show the request along with values being replace or the actual request being sent to the server.

```
//Check if you have got the response
assert context.response, "Response is null or empty"

//show the actual request is being sent
log.info context.rawRequest
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my log is `null`. If I sent `log.info context["myRequest#Request"]`, return XML with `${...}`. But I want to it return generated XML, which really send by HTTP.

Comment: Are you using script assertion as mentioned in the answer? Try as it is.

Comment: I try it again and now my log show generated XML, which really send by HTTP. Really THANK YOU.